# Routing To another page is not happening without refreshing after clicking on the link in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have one Navbar in React with the following code

```
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from './components/header/Header';
import Home from './components/home/Home';
import About from './components/about/About';
import Accessories from './components/accessories/Accessories';
import Category1 from './components/accessories/categories/Category1';
import Category2 from './components/accessories/categories/Category2';
import Category3 from './components/accessories/categories/Category3';
import Category4 from './components/accessories/categories/Category4';
import Contact from './components/contact/Contact';
import Footer from './components/footer/Footer';

const App = () => {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Header />
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/">
                        <Home />
                        <About />
                        <Accessories />
                        <Contact />
                    </Route>
                    <Route exact path="/category1">
                        <Category1 />
                    </Route>
                    <Route exact path="/category2">
                        <Category2 />
                    </Route>
                    <Route exact path="/category3">
                        <Category3 />
                    </Route>
                    <Route exact path="/category4">
                        <Category4 />
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
            <Footer />
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

I can go smoothly from `/` to `/category1`, but when I reroute to `/` from `/category1`, no rerendering is happening until I refresh the page.
I have no idea what to do now. Thank you for any help in advance

**Edited**: I just changes all my `Links` to anchor tags and now they are working but is it a good practice?

Comment: Can you explain how you are navigating from one route to another? Are you using the `Link` component?

Comment: Yes, I am using the `Link` to navigate from one page to another.

Comment: I just changes all my `Links` to anchor tags and now they are working, but is it a good practice?

Answer (score 1):

```
                    <Route exact path="/">
                        <Home />
                        <About />
                        <Accessories />
                        <Contact />
                    </Route>
```

Put the above code after all the routes are being defined and it should work

```
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/category1">
                <Category1 />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/category2">
                <Category2 />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/category3">
                <Category3 />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/category4">
                <Category4 />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/">
                <Home />
                <About />
                <Accessories />
                <Contact />
            </Route>
        </Switch>
```

The '/' path should be defined at the last after all the paths have been defined

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the  element to redirect to other routes. In "/category1", you can use the  element to redirect "/" without reloading the page.

Comment: Is there any way to do it by using `Link`